# How to rename multiple files

Tags: rename

I have files with names as,

```
A2002185.h23v04.005.2007177004246.hdf  
A2002201.h23v04.005.2008288062542.hdf
```

I want to rename them by deleting everything in the name after first dot (and have names as *A2002185.hdf*, *A2002201.hdf*), how can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Using `prename` (`rename` is a symlink to this by default on many systems):

```
prename -n 's:\..*\.:.:' *.hdf
```

The `-n` will print the actions that will be taken without doing anything. Once you are sure you have what you want, remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Run the below script from the folder where you have all these files.

```
for f in *.hdf; do mv -- "$f" "${f%%.*}".hdf ; done
```

The above script checks for all files with `hdf` extension inside the current directory and for each file, it removes the characters after the `.` character and adds the extension as `.hdf`